# Question about Work performed between two points within an electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, potential, work, potential-energy

In an exercise in my Physics Textbook, I was asked to calculate the amount of Work necessary to move a charge of -$1.6\cdot10^{-6}$ Coulomb from P to R, and from R to O (see attached picture below).

Based on other pieces of information given, I correctly calculated the Potential at P to be $-0.968609$, at O to be $-2.16 J$, and at R to be $0.921894 J$. I thought the rest would be really straightforward based on the formula $W=q(V_b-V_a)$, essentially just subtracting the Joules. However, the answer provided by the textbook does something that strikes me as very odd:

From P to R, I calculated as $0.921894 - (-0.968609)= 0.921894 + 0.968609 = 1.890503 J$
From R to O, I calculated as $-2.16-0.921894 = -3.081894 J$

The textbook gives the same formula with the same numbers but somehow inverts the minuses into pluses. There are some mistakes in the book here and there, so this might be one of them. Could somebody with deeper insight than myself let me know if this is correct or incorrect; and in case the textbook is correct, why the pluses and the minuses do not correspond?

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems like the textbook is wrong and you are right.

Comment: That would be good news, because I have been doubting myself the whole night...